# bootstrap data-id undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get value of data-id binded to modal.
Here is code

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true" data-target="#btnSendSMS" data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN564541"></i>
```

//popup model

```
   <div id="btnSendSMS" style="display: none" class="modal fade TransParentAll" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" id="C_Model_Dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" id="C_Model_Content">
                <div class="modal-header" id="C_Model_Header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Send SMS</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="C_modal_body">
                    <form class="AddFreelancerForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="pull-left">SMS</span>
                            <input type="text" id="textSMS" class="form-control" placeholder="write something here" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" id="C_Model_Footer">
                    <button id="btnsave" type="button" class="btn c_G_Btn pop_upSaveBtn" value="1" onclick="SendSMS()">
                        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Send
                    </button>
                    <button id="btnCancel" type="button" class="btn c_R_Btn" data-dismiss="modal" value="1" onclick="CloseWindow()">
                        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Close
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

//JS

```
function SendSMS() {
        var candidateId = $(this).data('id');
        var can=$(this).attr("data-id") ;
```

But i am getting undefined in both values on button click.

Comment: Are you include the [`jquery`](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js) library link ?

Comment: yes. I have already included

Comment: What does `this` refer in `SendSMS`?

Comment: The button `<button id="btnsave" type="button" class="btn c_G_Btn pop_upSaveBtn" value="1" onclick="SendSMS()">` has no ID, nor an attribute of `data-id`...

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote click event on `<button>` tag, `$(this)` will always refers to `<button>` object. So,
`var can=$(this).attr("data-id") ;` will always return undefined since `<button>` object don't have attribute called data-id

if you are trying to get id of `<button>` object, try below line

```
var candidateId = $(this).attr('id');
```

if `<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true" data-target="#btnSendSMS" data-toggle="modal" data-id="ISBN564541"></i>` is inside `<button>` object, you can get `data-id` with line:

```
var can=$(this).find("i").attr("data-id") ;
```

i.e your code will be like,

```
function SendSMS() {
        var candidateId = $(this).attr('id');
        var can=$(this).find("i").attr("data-id") ;
}
```